# Pattern lock/factory reset

Tags: factory-reset

My daughter put a pattern lock on my phone and now I can't unlock it. What can I do? Have tried the master resets but just reset the phone. Is anything else?
HTC desire 510

Answer (score 0):

Try This it will Hard reset your phone

> 1.Remove the battery, wait for a few seconds, then reinsert the battery.
>
> 2. Press and hold the VOLUME DOWN button, and then press and hold the POWER button.
> 3. Wait for the screen with the three Android images to appear, and then release the POWER and VOLUME DOWN buttons.
> 4. Press VOLUME DOWN to select FACTORY RESET, and then press the POWER button.

Comment: Did you read it somewhere? If yes, then please mention the link. If not, then there is no need to use quote.

Comment: @Firelord here is the Link http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-desire-510-cricket/howto/550842.html

Answer (score 0):

You could miss 30 times or more, you should get the username/password prompt. Then enter your email+password and your phone will unlock.

Also, note that your wifi/3g/4g needs to be on in order to verify with email/password combination. I had to make an app which would turn it on first, then I managed to unlock it

Answer (score -1):

You can boot into [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) (see our [recovery-mode tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) for details on how to achieve this) and choose wipe data/factory reset there. Then reboot your phone.

Note: this will delete all user-installed apps and data from the device.

Comment: usually with vol up + power button